# jQuery - best practises for defining variables

Tags: jquery

I am trying to define a variable by getting the attribute of an element. In addition to using the attribute I would like to add some html.

Is there a better way to do it then this?:

```
var tip = $(this).attr('title').append('<p>Take me to:</p>');
```

Comment: `var tip = '<p>Take me to: ' + $(this).attr('title') + '</p>';` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var tip = $('<p/>', {
    title: 'Take me to ' + $(this).attr("title")
});
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is pretty undefined behaviour. `attr(name)` returns the value of that attribute as a string, number, whatever it is. So, you can treat it like any other value.

```
`var tip = '<p>Take me to: '+$(this).attr('title')+'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple, and keep it a jQuery object:

```
var $tip = $('<p>Take me to: ' + $(this).attr('title') + '</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this).attr('title') will return the title, which you are trying to append the html to (which wouldn't work).

```
var x = $(this).append(html).attr('title');
```

should work (x will equal the title of the element).